# Function may be const or not depending on arguments

Tags: c++, refactoring

I'm trying to refactor some code by facotirising duplicate code.
Let's imagine I end up with a class like:

```
class A {
public:
void method1() 
{
  do_work(true);
}

void method2() const
{
  do_work(false);
}


private:
void do_work(bool flag) {
...
if(flag)
this->data = 0;
}
}
```

However this won't compile because do_work is not const, even though calling this method with flag = false is const.
Is there a way to "fix" this without splitting again the implementations?

Comment: Seems like `do_work` ought to be `const` or not be accessible from both member functions. Maybe you want a `bool` template argument and `if constexpr` instead. But I'm not sure how to specify that a member function's constness depends on a template argument. No matter what though, constness of the function can't depend on runtime information.

Comment: Sorry, C++ does not work this way. You'll need something along the lines of `void do_work_true()` and `void do_work_false() const`; and there can be further refactoring so that their common code is not duplicated. Whether a class method is `const` or not is specified at compile time, and not at run time based on some parameter. That's the only way that this works in C++.

Answer (score 2):

`do_work` is poorly refactored, as a function that is "sometimes const".

Separate out the `const` and non-const logic.

```
class A {

  void method1() 
  {
    do_work();
    this->data = 0;
  }

  void method2() const
  {
    do_work();
  }

private:

  void do_work() const {
    ...
  }
}
```

Comment: thanks but this was a limitation of my example. In the real case I basically have a loop that calls either a const method or a non-const method

Comment: I think there is merit to the core of the question, how make the `const`ness of a member function dependent on a constant expression. This sounds somewhat like how `noexcept` can have an optional condition expression. I'm not sure this is possible for `const`, but I'm also curious to find out.